# How to style answer box / add a new topic box

Tags: css, wordpress

I’m designing a wordpress website however I have no experience with html and CSS so when I need to fix bits and bobs of my website, I copy and paste CSS code that I manage to find online and it has been working so far.

The problem I have at the moment is I’m using a forum plugin called wpforo and I would like to edit how the reply / create new topic box looks. It looks very cluttered and unattractive (https://prnt.sc/paccv8).

What CSS could I add such that I could hide a few buttons? Here are some screenshots of how the answer box is laid out on my website. (divs and classes)

https://prnt.sc/pacddi

https://prnt.sc/pacdki

https://prnt.sc/pacea4

https://prnt.sc/paceha

https://prnt.sc/pacf09

Hiding some buttons would be the quick fix, if possible – what CSS could I add such that I could reveal the hidden buttons with an ‘advanced’ button then unreveal it with a ‘basic button’, here are two screenshots to demonstrate what I mean.

https://prnt.sc/pac5fm

https://prnt.sc/pac5py

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. Are you basically saying "My form is boring - what can I do to make it took better?"

Comment: CSS alone won't allow you to hide and show elements on the page. You'd have to employ some Javascript to handle the "advanced" button click to show the hidden elements.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for getting code written for you, if you have a problem that **you** are working to solve, we can help. Please include a good example of how you're trying to solve the problem, and a specific question regarding your code/problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think there's a slight miscommunication. I might have posted this in the wrong forum, if so I apologise. As I said, I have no experience with any coding so if anyone needs payment for such a task I would happily pay - where can I post this thread? Is there a "requests with payment" area?

Comment: @OnlineUser02094 Essentially that is what I'm saying! I didn't create this to put wpforo in a bad light, in fact I think its the best out of all the wordpress forum plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default you have is fine to be honest. If you want some space between elements, then you can use `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-left`, `margin-right` for an element. For example `#div-name{margin-bottom: 1rem}`. Also, if you want the same amount everywhere then insetad of specifying all top,bottom,left, right, you can just use `margin: 1rem` which will do it for all.

If you want the background colour to change like in one the examples then `background-color: blue` on the title div would work.

As for the basic and advance button options, you wont be able to do this with CSS. It would require Javascript/jQuery. There will be many tutorials online for how to hide/show elements using jquery, but I think (I haven't used Wordpress enough to know if this is true) you will need to create some javascript file and then attach it to the page somehow. It's a lot of new stuff for a beginner to learn. I would just stick with what you have.

I would also suggest [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) as a quick way to learn some basic CSS, which might give you enough to get what you want.

Remember, CSS is for styling, Javascript is for functionality.